# Convert a 3d array to a 4d array

Tags: python, arrays, reshape

I have a matrix and I am obtaining a 2 channel matrix with images having size 256x120.
Now, I need to store several images so I need to reshape my matrix to (No.ofimages,256,120,2).

I tried to use reshape and then append:

But I am getting a `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable` when using reshape

Any ideas on how I can solve it?

Comment: You can't reshape `(112, 112, 2)` to `(14394,112,112,2)`. Not sure what is your `input_shape` that you are using.

Comment: You should create the matrix with size ``(14394,112,112,2)`` and then store your first image with size ``(112, 112, 2)`` inside it as first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my current understanding of your issue:

```py
import numpy as np

img = np.random.random((112,112,2))
print(img.shape)

result = np.empty((0, 112, 112, 2))  # first axis is zero, for adding images along it

for i in range(100):        # replace this loop with something that reads in the images
    result = np.append(result, img[np.newaxis, ...], axis=0)    # add a new axis to each image and append them to result

print(result.shape)
```

Will produce:

```bash
(112, 112, 2)
(100, 112, 112, 2)
```

To access the images stored in the result variable, simply use indexing:

```py
print(result[1].shape)   # e.g., access the second image
```

Will produce:

```bash
(112, 112, 2)
```